# Saving loaded data when pausing an activity or fragment

Tags: android, save, onpause

I have been loading data from a server and presenting it in a listview or gridview but every time i pause the activity or minimize it, the data is reloaded when i go back to the said activity.

I know it is possible to save strings, integers or booleans at onSaveInstanceState but is there a way to save other data objects such as ArrayLists of objects, bearing in mind that some of the fragments are nested inside other fragments, which makes using setRetainInstance(true) unviable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can save anything into onSaveInstanceState as long as you make sure it implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

The longer, but possibly better solution for your situation is to use the [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) callbacks to load your stuff from the internet. This decouples your data from the activity life-cycle, freeing you from a lot of the pains of all that runtime changes entail.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a link for the official android guide to handle this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

basically you save your data ( ArrayList of Objects) in the fragment and when the Activity is restored you retrieve the data from the fragment.

The Fragment is not destroyed in between Activity change states or during runtime changes.

This is how your Fragment should look like:

```
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {

    // data object we want to retain
    private ArrayList<YourObject> data;

    // this method is only called once for this fragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<YourObject> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ArrayList<YourObject> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And your onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // store the data in the fragment
        dataFragment.setData(collectMyLoadedData());
    }
```

And your onCreate() method should be the same the only difference is how you load your data on this line:

```
dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
```

For your nested fragment problem check this link http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Comment: This only works for fragments that arent nested inside other fragments, and i have a couple inside a ViewPager contained in a fragment. How would i approach this?

Comment: Thats another question, or just update the question above. When it comes to nested fragments in android its really tricky to save data and a lot of bugs start to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data in fragment call the method `setRetainInstance( )`in your fragments,this way your fragment won't be destroyed during runtime changes,
you can save the custom objects by parceling it and writing to bundle in the `onSaveInstanceState`callback method of your activity and retrieve it in `onCreate` or `OnRestart`  callbacks.
I hope this [blog post](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/) may help you understand the things in detail